# Junit5: dynamic assert works abnormally in dynamic test

Tags: java, junit5

I'm using Junit5. I want to implement a dynamic test where test cases are defined in a YAML file. Now I'm hitting a problem as the title.

Looking at my sample code:

```
@Test
public void t1() throws Exception {
    java.lang.reflect.Method method = org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.class.getMethod("assertEquals", int.class, int.class);
    method.invoke(null, 1, 5);
}

@TestFactory
Collection<DynamicTest> dynamicTests() {
    DynamicTest[] list = new DynamicTest[1];
    list[0] = DynamicTest.dynamicTest("dt1", new Executable() {
        @Override
        public void execute() throws Throwable {
            java.lang.reflect.Method method = org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.class.getMethod("assertEquals", int.class, int.class);
            method.invoke(null, 1, 50);
        }
    });
    return Arrays.asList(list);
}
```

In the sample code, I defined a static test case t1 and a dynamic test caes dt1. In both tests, I just do a dynamic assert.

But looking at the test result:

```
Failures (2):
  JUnit Jupiter:TestRunner:t1()
    MethodSource [className = 'com.mycompany.test.TestRunner', methodName = 't1', methodParameterTypes = '']
    => org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <5>
       org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:52)
       org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual (AssertEquals.java:197)
       org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals (AssertEquals.java:154)
       org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals (AssertEquals.java:149)
       org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:305)
       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       com.mycompany.test.TestRunner.t1(TestRunner.java:82)
       [...]
  JUnit Jupiter:TestRunner:dynamicTests():dt1
    MethodSource [className = 'com.mycompany.test.TestRunner', methodName = 'dynamicTests', methodParameterTypes = '']
    => java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       com.mycompany.test.TestRunner$1.execute(TestRunner.java:96)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor. executeAndMaskThrowable (JupiterTestDescriptor.java:141)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor. execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:41)
       org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor. execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:24)
       org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical. HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3 (HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
       org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor. executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
       [...]
```

For t1, assert shows properly as `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <5>`, but for dt1, assert shows `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. Did anybody see the same problem? How to get expected assert result as t1 for dt1?

Comment: fup2 https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1322

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the cause of `InvocationTargetException`. It should read something along the lines of:

```
Caused by: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <50>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:52)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:154)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:305)
    ...
```

If you think this not the desired behaviour, please file an issue at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues

If you replace your reflective method invocation in `dt1` with `Assertions.assertEquals(1, 50);` you'll get the `AssertionFailedError` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in JUnit Jupiter's [issue tracker](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1322#issuecomment-370826612), the solution to this issue is not to write your own reflective code for invoking methods in `Assertions` but rather to simply delegate to `ReflectionSupport` to ensure that the `InvocationTargetException` is properly unwrapped.

For example, the following should work for you in both cases.

```
ReflectionSupport.invokeMethod(method, null, 1, 5);
```